# Windows 8 Freezes At 100% Disk Usage

Tags: windows, windows-8, freeze, skype

I've read that a lot of people are having this problem, but nothing I try works. Disk usage will remain low until I launch a program like Skype. When I do, it will say that Skype uses around 1 megabyte, which is apparantly 100% of my disk capacity. Response is slow and I can't really do much. I've gone into task manager and I've checked what I/O is reading and writing the most, and before I disabled it, it had been Windows Search, and after, it seems it's SVChost and System.

It's definitely not malware or anything-- I've formatted and reinstalled my entire computer, which I had hoped would fix the problem. It didn't. I am sitting here with a fresh install of Windows 8, a powerful computer, and still it is freezing up. I really need your help, guys! It's driving me nuts.

Comment: What's your hardware configuration? Does it happen with other programs too, or only with Skype? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: I found out what the problem was! Skype was causing the problem, and was conflicting with something.. I believe the latest Win8 update did it. To remedy the situation, I downloaded an older version of Skype, and now it's working perfectly. I only wish I knew this BEFORE I reinstaled my computer haha!

Answer (score 0):

### *The solution is:*

1. **Download [SkypeSetup_6.9.0.106.msi](http://download.skype.com/msi/SkypeSetup_6.9.0.106.msi).**
2. **Get the file (Skype.exe) from within it.**
3. **Move and replace (Skype.exe) into *"Program Files\Skype\Phone\"*** (for example: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone")
4. *Before you open Skype you can delete the cache* **Otherwise Enjoy :D**

OR

2.**Uninstall Skype** using *[Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features]*

3.**Delete : "Skype" Folder from *"Program Files\"*** (for example: "C:\Program Files (x86)\")

4.**Delete the folder : "Skype" from *"Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming"*** (or for example: "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming")

5.**Install Skype** by *SkypeSetup*_6.9.0.106.*msi* **Enjoy :D**

### *The Problem is:*

for more information about this problem, you can search Google, but it seems that's an I/O problem with noSQL databases :/ and here a good description of the problem [Loading Delays, Computer Lagging, and Repeat Direct I/O Disk](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Loading-Delays-Computer-Lagging-and-Repeat-Direct-I-O-Disk/td-p/2358939).

Anyway it's because something messy in the last update of **Skype 6.11**

Comment: This is a serious issue and may cause a lot of problems. Many people can't even notice that Skype is the cause.